# PHPUnit - Trying to call a method from an object passed in as a parameter

Tags: phpunit

I'm trying to test calling a method of a request object which was passed into my function as a parameter, but I keep getting an error. Any idea what I could be doing wrong? Here's what I have:

In my action helper

```
public function direct($request)
{
    $myData = $request->getPost('myData');
}
```

In my test file

```
public function testDirect()
{
    $subject = $this->getMockBuilder('Default_Controller_Action_Helper_MyFile')
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->setMethods(
            array(
                'direct'
            )
        )
        ->getMock();

    $myData = 'myData';

    $request = $this->getMockBuilder('Zend_Controller_Request_Http')
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->setMethods(array('getPost'))
        ->getMock();

    $request->expects($this->exactly(1))
        ->method('getPost')
        ->with('myData')
        ->will($this->returnValue($myData));

    $subject->direct($request);
}
```

I get the following error:

```
There was 1 failure:

1) Default_Controller_Action_Helper_MyFile::testDirect
Expectation failed for method name is equal to <string:getPost> when invoked 1 time(s).
Method was expected to be called 1 times, actually called 0 times.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass `null` to `setMethods()` in `$subject` definition to prevent mocking the methods from your class.

It's not enough to drop the `setMethods` call as the mock builder mocks all methods by default.

This should work:

```
public function testDirect()
{
    $subject = $this->getMockBuilder('Default_Controller_Action_Helper_MyFile')
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->setMethods(null)
        ->getMock();

    $myData = 'myData';

    $request = $this->getMockBuilder('Zend_Controller_Request_Http')
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->setMethods(array('getPost'))
        ->getMock();

    $request->expects($this->exactly(1))
        ->method('getPost')
        ->with('myData')
        ->will($this->returnValue($myData));

    $subject->direct($request);
}
```

Comment: hmm same error after removing setMethods from $subject.

Comment: My bad, looks like the mockbuilder mocks all the methods by default. To prevent it, you should pass `null` to `setMethods`. I updated my answer.